# body{background-color: red;} is not working in external css

Tags: css

"this is my external css file of name **style.css**"

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}

h3{
  color: #66BFBF;
}

hr{
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey; 
  border-width: 3px;  
  width: 5%;
}
```

"And this is my html file of name index.html .in which the style.css linked correctly because hr selector working ,but not others."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chandan's personal site</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="CSS\style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is me!<h1>
    <hr>
    <h3>Books & Learning</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in the network panel of your inspector. do you see any errors? The `CSS\style.css` seems incorrect to me. i think it should be `CSS/style.css`. Give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i delete the line out - <lang 'en'>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).